# Create a dialogbox from another class with its own thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm making a very little game in a "GameView" with a "GameThread" inside it. It extends from View so I use this constructor:

```
GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
//initialization stuff
}
```

and I add it on the main_activity.xml because its controlled by buttons. The problem is that I want to make that when the game is over, it shows a Dialog with the score. But I don't know how to do this. I 've tried creating a reference to the context with a class attribute like this:

```
GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
this.context = context;
}
```

But i can't call "runOnUIThread" with this.

Comment: to call runOnUiThread you need an Activity reference for that , but you can create a dialog using context with [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UI thread's handler instead. Get an instance using your context and post your Runnable

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something in your UI thread
                }
            };
            handler.post(myRunnable);
```

Comment: When i put that in the gamethread it says me "unreachable statement". How can i solve this?

Comment: Put it before the `return` statement.

Comment: I've put it on the run method of the "GameThread" after the while cicle that controls the game, but it still doesn't work,  in the Handler definition it says the same thing "unreachable statement". I don't understand what's the problem...

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! it wasn't the problem!!!, the game cycle was set as "true" so all code under that would be unreachable...i feel so stupid...